# Why is the address in EDX increased by 1 byte after lstrlen?

Tags: assembly

I am currently learning about assembly and am therefore trying some simple crackmes or just looking at different programs in assembly. But now i stumbled across a very strange case, which i am unable to understand.
The code looks like this:

```
LEA, EDX, [406349]
PUSH EDX
CALL <JMP.&kernel32.lstrlenA>
```

Nothing scary really. In my understanding the address for the string get loaded into the EDX register and then pushed on the stack as an argument for `strlen`. And i can follow this process in OllyDbg. 
The strange thing happens after the function call. The address in `EDX` is suddenly increased by 1 byte, and therefore points to the second character of the string.
Why does this happen?

Comment: Hmm… It probably is allowed to happen because EDX is a scratch register in the ABI relevant to the platform you are using, and you didn't tell us what it was, so there's not much to say.

Comment: I am working on a x64 platform, with an 32-bit OllyDbg version. And i believe the application was also built for 32-bit systems.

Comment: WHAT OS ARE YOU USING?

Comment: Oh ups. Meant to also put it up there. Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application is a 32-bit application for Windows/x86, so it uses the stdcall calling convention for calling system functions. From the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions):

> **stdcall**
>
> The stdcall calling convention is a variation on the Pascal calling
>   convention in which the callee is responsible for cleaning up the
>   stack, but the parameters are pushed onto the stack in right-to-left
>   order, as in the _cdecl calling convention. **Registers EAX, ECX, and
>   EDX are designated for use within the function.** Return values are
>   stored in the EAX register.
>
> **stdcall is the standard calling convention for the Microsoft Win32 API**
>   and for Open Watcom C++.

In all likelihood, `EDX` appears to be incremented inside the function because the function reads the argument from the stack into `EDX`, and then increments it in order to align it so as to then read characters 32 bits at a time.

It doesn't matter much for what reasons it is modified, though: the function is allowed to modify `EDX` (and `ECX`). It could also contain on return an arbitrary value with no relation to the original value, and the function would still be respecting the ABI.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This kinda suggests that the developer did write parts of the asm code himself, doesn't it? Or would the compiler do something like this under any circumstance?

Comment: @puelo It is entirely possible to write low-level C code that cares about alignment. Anyway, you could use your debugger to step into the function and see what it does. Did my answer give the impression that `EDX` has simply been incremented? It is likely that it ends up containing the address + 1 because the address has been read from the stack and been but there before being incremented. There is no point in the function manipulating `EDX` directly since the ABI does not say this is how arguments are passed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It was quite clear. The EDX is later in the function used to read each character byte by byte. I was just wondering if the compiler would ever structure it like this, or if had to be done purposely by the developer? I mean using the EDX register to store the address before the function call and still use it afterwards, even though the function uses the stdcall calling convention?

Comment: @puelo This sounds like a very dangerous thing to do either by a compiler or by a human. In fact, a compiler would probably not make this mistake. Perhaps a human has written the code that you are looking at, and never noticed that it was buggy because it happened to work for the intended purpose with Windows' `strlen` implementation. Raymond Chen's blog contains quite a few horror stories about keeping buggy applications working in new versions of Windows, this could be one of them. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/